# WCF Rest Service: Tool for creating strongy typed classes via the help pages?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, strong-typing

can anyone tell me if there is a tool for creating the strongly typed classes (available via the schema)  - i suppose similar to Paste as XML type ..

But i was hoping for a tool that i could run to automatically update the classes automatically when there are changes

Does anyone know if something like this exists?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a WCF Data Service (f.k.a. "Astoria" or "ADO.NET Data Service"), you can use the regular `Add Service Reference` in Visual Studio, point it to the SVC file for the service, and voila - you get a data service client side proxy, with strong types and all, and the ability to query your data service (a REST service) using LINQ - LINQ-to-REST, so to speak!

See the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd673930%28VS.100%29.aspx) for a few more bits of info.